# Python: setting values of a list of nested dictionaries in class instances

Tags: python, list, dictionary, setter

I have a burning question that I just can't figure out. Let's say you have a class, and this class takes in as input a list of nested dictionaries. It initializes one of the keys of each of these dictionaries with a new, empty dictionary. Later, I want to set one of the nested values of an object in the list as something. For some reason this seems to affect other objects in the list?

I know that's sounds very convoluted, so here's an example:

```
class Tester():
    def __init__(self, stuff):

        # stuff is a list of dictionaries
        self.stuff = stuff

        # Each item in the list should be initialized to this dictionary
        inside_init_dict = {'test': True}
        for x in self.stuff:
            x['info'] = inside_init_dict

if __name__ == '__main__':
    new_stuff = [{'info': {}}, {'info': {}}, {'info': {}}]
    mytest = Tester(new_stuff)

    print(mytest.stuff)
    # >>> [{'info': {'test': True}}, {'info': {'test': True}}, {'info': {'test': True}}]

    # I want to just set a value in the nested dict of the first item in the list
    mytest.stuff[0]['info']['test'] = False

    # However, all items in the list change
    print(mytest.stuff)
    # >>> [{'info': {'test': False}}, {'info': {'test': False}}, {'info': {'test': False}}]
```

This happens on both Python 2 and 3. The only way I can get around this is to not use the separate variable "inside_init_dict", and directly set the initialized dictionary:

```
class Tester():
    def __init__(self, stuff):

        # stuff is a list of dictionaries
        self.stuff = stuff

        # Each item in the list should be initialized to this dictionary
        for x in self.stuff:
            x['info'] = {'test': True}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    new_stuff = [{'info': {}}, {'info': {}}, {'info': {}}]
    mytest = Tester(new_stuff)

    print(mytest.stuff)
    # >>> [{'info': {'test': True}}, {'info': {'test': True}}, {'info': {'test': True}}]

    mytest.stuff[0]['info']['test'] = False

    # This is what I want
    print(mytest.stuff)
    # >>> [{'info': {'test': False}}, {'info': {'test': True}}, {'info': {'test': True}}]
```

What's going on here? I have tried setting the variable "inside_init_dict" in various places, like as a class variable or outside the class. The issue still occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the keys to different copies of the `inside_init_dict` dictionary instead of the same one:

```
    ...
    inside_init_dict = {'test': True}
    for x in self.stuff:
        x['info'] = inside_init_dict.copy()
```

Comment: @deckardk If I get what you're asking, you're essentially assigning them to the same object. Updating from one reference changes the object, and the change is reflected across all others.

Answer (score 3):

In the first example you create a single dictionary `inside_init_dict` outside the loop and put it in multiple places. Every element of the list gets that same `inside_init_dict`. What you're seeing is not other objects in a list being affected, there's just one object being shown multiple times.

In the second example:

```
    for x in self.stuff:
        x['info'] = {'test': True}
```

Now each `x` gets its own dictionary. They all have the same value at first, but they are different instances, like identical twins.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for explaining it that way. Makes sense to me now.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because `dicts` are [mutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056130/immutable-vs-mutable-types), meaning that you can change their content without changing their identity. Here's a much simpler example of the behavior you're seeing:

```
my_dict = { "key" : "value" }
my_list = [ my_dict, my_dict ]
my_list[0]["key"] = "new_value"
print(my_list) # [ {"key" : "new_value"}, {"key": "new_value"} ]
```

**Why this happens:**

In the first line of this code, I create a new dictionary, `{"key" : "value"}`, and assign the name `my_dict` to it.

In the second line, I create a list, whose zeroth and first element *both* point to `my_dict`.

In the third line, I access `my_dict` (through `my_list[0]`), and I *mutate* it: changing the value associated with `"key"`.

In the  fourth line, I check the value of `my_list`. Both the zeroth and the first element of `my_list` still point to `my_dict` -- and we've changed `my_dict`. So the change is reflected in both elements of the list.

**One way to fix it:**

Instead pointing to the same dictionary twice, create two dictionaries that have the same value:

```
my_list = [ { "key" : "value" } , { "key" : "value" } ] 
my_list[0]["key"] = "new_value"
print(my_list) # [ {"key" : "new_value"}, {"key": "value"} ]
```